# limiting the selection between two dates in daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I want the date I will choose after the first date to be 15 days at most. I used the x property but it didn't.

```js
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a maxSpan option, see https://www.daterangepicker.com/#options

> maxSpan: (object) The maximum span between the selected start and end
> dates. Check off maxSpan in the configuration generator for an example
> of how to use this. You can provide any object the moment library
> would let you add to a date.